# How to set default input format for admin?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Does anyone know, how to set a default input format only for admin?

I use tinyMCE. And when I add a page, I need "full html" input format (to add an image for example). But default is "filtered html". I can switch it, but tinyMCE doesn't work then.

Also I don't want to set "full html" by default. I want tinyMCE to be used only by admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 6, use Better Formats (http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) to specify default format per role and a whole lot of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `/admin/settings/filters/defaults`. You can set the default input format per role (and per node/comment/etc). If you set "Full HTML" for the administrator role under "Node", but set "Filtered HTML" for the authenticated/anonymous roles that should do what you want.

Comment: There's no page by this path. (I use drupal 6.22.)